# How to update a page's DOM with JQuery, when the page processes images on the fly?

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

Quite similar to Facebook comments, I have built a messaging system for users.

Each comment has a small picture of their profile pic next to it. I'm doing this by getting ColdFusion to resize the main profile image down into a smaller size. It does this on the fly so that I don't have to store a large and small version of the same profile image.

If the comment is new, then the profile pic is say 50x50px. But if the comment is a reply then it will be around 30x30px.  Again the sizing is taken care of by a ColdFusion function.

If I AJAX submit the comment form, I would like the comment to appear on the page without a refresh. I can get all the information I need to update the DOM from a JSON object that ColdFusion returns after inserting the new comment. **However**, the profile image filename returned will point to the original large picture. If I pass this original large image to the DOM, then ColdFusion resize function can't see it so I end up with a massive image as their profile pic.

So how does one do things like this using AJAX and JQuery to update the DOM when there are elements on the page that need application server processing?

Comment: how to do what? And what is a `CF resize function`?

Comment: @charliefl it just resizes an image e.g. ImageScaleToFit(myImage.jpg, 150, 150). So its saying get the image and scale it so that it fits within a 150px by 150x box. It maintains the aspect ratio so the image isn't all skewed.

Comment: fairly simple to do it with css, different class for smaller image

Comment: *so that I don't have to store a large and small version* Why? Image functions are resource intensive. Space is cheap. It is more efficient to do image manipulation once, rather multiple times - on every http request.

Comment: @Leigh I didn't know this. I just didn't think that Facebook or other giants would store multiple versions of the same image especially when they use CSS sprites for images to keep thinks quick and snappy.

Comment: While there is some overlapping, that is a different concept. Image resizing takes place on the CF server. It can eat up a lot of CF's resources. So resizing once, rather than multiple times on *every* http request, improves CF performance. Sprites, on the other hand, aim to improve web server performance by reducing the overall number of http requests and taking advantage of image caching.

Comment: @Leigh I have product images which need to be shown in a catalogue for quick browsing. I am resizing those images using ImageScaleToFit() on the fly for each http request. When the user clicks on a product, it takes you to the detail page with the image shown in full. Are you suggesting then that storing multiple sizes of these images is better for performance?

Comment: Better than dynamic resizing *on the server*, yes. On busy sites, you might end up resizing the same image thousands of times. That can chew up resources and negatively impact other parts of the application. Why waste cpu on doing the same task over and over? Plus, resizing takes additional time, making it slower, not faster.

Answer (score 1):

While css is probably the simpler way to go, you could still use your ImageScaleToFit() call to get your image.

If you move this function to its own script or remote function, you could pass the file name to it and have it return the resized image.

Single file example:

```
<cfset image_obj = ImageRead(url.image)>
<cfset ImageScaleToFit(image_obj, 50, 50)>

<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=myimage.jpg">
<cfcontent variable="#ToBinary(ToBase64(image_obj))#" type="image/jpeg">
```

Remote function example:

```
<cffunction access="remote" name="renderImage" output="true" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="image" type="string" required="true">

    <cfset var image_obj = ImageRead(arguments.image)>
    <cfset ImageScaleToFit(image_obj, 150, 150)>

    <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=myimage.jpg">
    <cfcontent variable="#ToBinary(ToBase64(image_obj))#" type="image/jpeg">
</cffunction>
```

Then just set the source of your image tag to reference your script or remote function call, with the image file name returned from your ajax call as the image variable.

Single file example:

```
<img src="/image_scale.cfm?image=myimage.jpg">
```

Remote function example:

```
<img src="/image.cfc?method=renderImage&image=myimage.jpg">
```

It's a bit transparent, and you could use rewrite rules to create a bit more obfuscation, but it will do the trick.

If you do want to use CSS, you could simply use the max-width/max-height style to scale the image down. It will still be the full image, so if you're worried about file size this will not alleviate that.

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" style="max-width:150px; max-height:150px;">
```

Not sure what your user base is, but you can see supported browsers and their versions here: [WWW3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp)

Comment: So when the image source is returned as a string from the JSON, Coldfusion can work with that filename to resize it? I don't understand how.

Comment: It's resizing it the same way you are doing now (via ImageScaleToFit()) you just pass it the path to the file via a URL parameter. Are you not using the file path right now to resize it?

Comment: I am using a filepath, but the filename comes from the database. So in my JSON it will be like `"Profile":{"Fullname":"John Smith","ProfileImg":"myface.jpg"}` So in JQuery I'll take this and do an append to a list something like `<li><img src="myface.jpg" /></li>` So the webpage displays the full size pic of myface.jpg whereas if it was coming from the database it would do this instead `<li><cfimage source="#ExpandPath('/images/myface.jpg')#" name="ProfilePic"/><cfset ImageScaleToFit(ProfilePic, 30, 30, "highestPerformance")><cfimage source="#ProfileImg#" action="writeToBrowser"></li>`

Comment: So can we assume that all of your image files are going to be in the same folder? That is, are all of these images in the "/images/" folder?

Comment: It would be more like "images/userid/mypic.jpg" with userid being the unique id given to that user in the database table.

Comment: You would have to pass that information along to the script as well. You would have to give it the relative (to the root) path in order for it to know where the file is to resize it. Although I do agree with @Leigh, if this is oft occurring, you're likely to be worse off than just creating multiple sizes for every image.